# How can I query from PostgreSQL not one by one?

Tags: python, postgresql

I`m a newbie to Postgres, so i have a question.
For example, I have list of ids like this:

`id_list = [1623834,1634438,1638483...]`
and I have 200000 ids like this.

I want to query all these 200000 ids from PostgreSQL Database and get all of the information about them.

But if i will do like this:

```
for i in list of ids:
      postgreSQL_select_Query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(id)
```

it might take a while  to query.
So can anyone recommend me some way, how can I query massively? not one by one?

---

I did it like this:

```
"SELECT /*+ parallel (4) */ * FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(id)
```

Comment: i would guess instead of this try to find min and max of `id_list` fetch all data match with list like `SELECT  FROM users WHERE id > min or id < max` or you use `IN` clause of sql

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce this to one query by doing the following:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (1623834,1634438,1638483,...)
```

I am not sure how well this would perform with a list of the size that you mentioned, but it might work for a one-time query and at least you are not running 100,000s of individual queries.

Answer (score 0):

Your Postgres Query should look like this:
`"SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ANY(ids)"`